Efcore .net core Change table names runtime
I have a .net core mvc project. This project receives data by connecting to the API.
I want to change the table names in my efcore structure by checking the company number of the user in each connection.
For example, let the user have 3 companies. In the database, I create tables such as _001,_002_003... apart from the common tables. Whichever company the user chose when logging in, the non-shared tables of that company must be selected. I achieve this every time the api starts. However, after logging out, I cannot update the table names again when I log in by selecting another company. How can I change this in dbcontext every time I log in to the API? Thank you in advance for your help...

Multi-tenancy

This is not a recommended pattern for managing multi-tenancy in EF.
But it can be done with a Dynamic Model.
